# MSBuild 2019 ignores INCLUDE environment variable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, msbuild, include

I am working with two machines that have Visual Studio 2019.  One has Community edition, the other has Pro edition.

The pro edition of MSBuild is completely ignoring the INCLUDE environment variable, so the project I'm trying to build (ICU) cannot find stddef.h.  The stddef.h file is in the Windows Kits 10 ucrt directory, which is included in the INCLUDE env var.

The community edition doesn't do this.

When I build the project with the /v:diag option I can see most of what's defined in the INCLUDE env var is added to a variable named CAExcludePath.

Here's the INCLUDE env var: `INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\atlmfc\include;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\UnitTest\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt;;`

And here's the CAExcludePath: `CAExcludePath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt;;`

Why does this happen and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Did you follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) to install Windows Kits tool?  In general, you should set these paths in VS IDE rather than environment variable. In my side, when l follow the steps of the installer and finish the last step to install Windows Driver Kit, l can use it directly in the code since it has included into `Include Directories` .automatically

Comment: I installed the necessary tool kits in the visual studio installer.  Which is why they are added to the INCLUDE path by the native tools command prompt for VS (see Kit directories in the INCLUDE env var I posted).  I did not however install the Windows Driver Kit.  That's not needed for the ICU project.  But if WDK alters VS behavior so it doesn't ignore the INCLUDE var then I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

> MSBuild 2019 ignores INCLUDE environment variable

I think you should not set these paths into **Environment Variables**. For C++ projects, VS does not recognize the library path in system environment variables by default and this is not the VS job.

**Usually**, you should set extra library paths in VS IDE. Right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`VC++ Directories`-->`Include Directories` or `Properties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`C/C++`-->`Additional Include Directories`. You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2019).

**However**, when l install **Windows Kits tool**, this path is included in the include path by default and you can use this in your code directly. See this:

[image]

**So** l am afraid you have something wrong when you install the **Windows Kits tool**. Please follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) to install the right tool and before you finish it, please install the related extension which is the last step in the installer in Visual Studio 2019 to integrate the tool.

I think when you install the extension, these paths will be included into VS automatically and you can use them directly.

[image]

**Besides**, if you do not want to install this extension, you can add the include path manually by the steps I mentioned above.

If you have done these steps and still faced the same error, I think you should check your Environment and follow these suggestions:

**1)** close VS Instance, delete `.vs`, `bin`, `obj` folders,reopen your project and then build again

**2)**  [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer

**3)** if your VS is not the latest, please update your VS and do not forget to  update Operation System at the same time.

Hope these help.

Comment: Well, this sort of helps, because you say "VS does not recognize the library path in system environment variables by default".  But then why does community edition of VS recognize them?  Seems to me like this behavior should be consistent - and configurable.  Ultimately my question is: how do you configure VS so it doesn't ignore the INCLUDE env var values?  I can tweak the ICU project file on a per system basis, but that is less than ideal.  Should be able to just run MSBuild from the command-line using native developer command prompt (which adds tool kits to INCLUDE path) and it should work.

Comment: I would like to re-iterate that building with MSBuild from the native tools command prompt does work with community edition.  So I'm just trying to figure out how to get pro edition to do the same (configure it so it doesn't ignore paths in the INCLUDE env var).

Comment: The `INCLUDE` info which you showed from msbuild diag is just transfered by msbuild target which is from VS internal include path. And if you delete the `INCLUDE environment vaiables` in Community edition, did you face the same error? If you do not face the same error, I think the issue is not related to `INCLUDE environment variables`. As for me, when I install the tool `Windows Universal CRT SDK` in vs installer, msbuild will load these path automatically.

Comment: So please open [Developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) in Pro edition and then type `echo %INCLUDE%`, and can you see these paths? If not, please l think there are some erros in your vs environemnt. So please do some repairs as l said above.

Comment: I got the INCLUDE=... part of the original post from doing just that.  The paths in the INCLUDE env var setup by the developer command prompt are correct.  The paths exist and contain the correct files.  MSBuild from VS Pro just refuses to use them.

Comment: At this point I've given up on getting MSBuild to use the INCLUDE env var and have resorted to manually changing the VS project files on a per machine basis to be hard-coded to include the correct paths.  So much for automated builds.  :-(

Comment: I tries to compile ruby on msvc: added additional directories, installed all available driver kits, made VS repair and rebooted virtual machine with windows 10 times, it didn't help. It is windows, nothing will help, only disassembly and reassembly will help to allow just small `INCLUDE` variable...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IncludePath` environment variable instead.

```
set IncludePath=%INCLUDE%
```

`IncludePath` is not ignored/overwritten when running `msbuild`, and I was able to successfully compile my project/solution by setting it.

On my machine, setting `IncludePath` overrides 3 paths which would otherwise be set. The 3 paths have analogs (same header files but for different versions) in my `%INCLUDE%` paths, so it seems safe (and in fact prudent) to ignore/clobber/leave these out.